# Conditional display of CCK field for certain profiles values

Tags: entities, users

I have created a content type with CCK on Drupal 7, and I would like to display only a few fields according to certain values in their profile2 type.

Concretely, I have a profile2 field to specify if the member is VAT registered or not. When the members are submitting their invoices, I want to display specific fields if they are VAT registered.

Answer (score 1):

for this you have to create a field on your content type called vat registered or not. Autofill that field from profile 2 field for the specific users. Then use conditional module. If that field is filled by default show some fields otherwise do not show that fields.

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: for this you have to create a field on your content type called vat registered or not . and autofill that field from profile 2 field for the specific users. and then use conditional module .if that field is filled by default show some fields otherwise do not show that fields.

Comment: Please use [edit](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/125427/edit) button next time.

Answer (score 0):

you will likely need to use [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) in a [custom module](https://www.drupal.org/developing/modules/7). The simplest way is to create the ecommerce section WITH the VAT fields as default, and then hide the fields if a condition is met (the profile doesn't contain the VAT).  exactly how depends on field names and a few variables like accessing profile2 info that I'm not sure about, but this is the basic setup I think:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id)  {

    // get Devel module(https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) for this line
    dpm($form_id);
    // this will output information on ALL forms - remove when complete, but use this to
    // get the correct form machine name if you can't find it elsewhere, as well as 
    // determining the correct structure of the form in order to hide the fields further down

    switch ($form_id)  {
        case 'ecommerce_form':
            // pull data on $user (global $user)
            // you may need to use some direct db access (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_select/7)
            // to get profile2 info (I don't remember if it links into $user directly or not)
            // if statement - if field in profile contains value (assuming a boolean)
            // if so, do nothing (VAT is set to visible by default)
            // if not, hide VAT fields
            break;
     }
  }
```

do a simple search for modifying a form (hiding an element), there are thousands of examples and tutorials out there.

helpful link: [Form API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7) - reference on form manipulation